# Is there a quantifier more powerful than the other to determine FOL connector?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic, propositional-logic

So basically we have 2 types of quantifier in first order logic, they are universal quantifier and existential quantifier. Usually we use implies connector(->) when we have universal quantifier in front of our formula and use conjunction connector(∧) when we have existential quantifier in front of our formula.

1. If we have both quantifiers in front of our formula, which connector we should choose? (e.g. implies or conjunction) Or can it be both? (i.e. can be any connector between implies and conjunction but only pick one, or must use both of them?)
2. Does the order matter? (i.e. does it affect the decision of connector we should used if we put universal quantifier first then existential quantifier or vice versa?)

Example :

Everyone knows someone who hates either Joe or Judy

∀x∃y(knows(x,y)->(hates(y,Joe) V hates(y,Judy)))

Does above FOL equivalent to :

∀x∃y(knows(x,y)∧(hates(y,Joe) V hates(y,Judy)))

Or Neither of them meet the FOL criteria because we must use both connectors?

Comment: In your example, they are not equivalent. The second is the correct interpretation of "everyone knows someone who hates either Joe or Judy". The first means something totally different (for every $x$, there is a $y$ such that **if** $x$ knows $y$ then $y$ hates Joe or Judy. In simple terms, it means that either $x$ doesn't know anyone, or $x$ knows someone that hates Judy or Joe)

Answer (score 0):

Observe, first, that the First-Order Logic (FOL) version that you have defined in the first statement adds some (syntactic) constraints and it turns out that this is a *fragment* of FOL, called *guarded fragment* [1]. In particular, such fragment answers the question:

> What precisely are fragments of classical first-order logic showing "modal" behaviour?

which is related to Modal Logic (ML). Moreover, ML is the fragment of FOL which is invariant under bisimulation [1].

---

In your example, to prove, then, that

$$
\forall x \exists y (knows(x,y) \to (hates(y,Joe) \lor hates(y,Judy))) \\ 
\leftrightarrow \\
\forall x \exists y (knows(x,y) \land (hates(y,Joe) \lor hates(y,Judy))).
$$

is not true, you can use the following argument as a counter-example. Imagine a scenario where $\neg knows(x,y)$ holds, for all $x$ and for some $y$, which (trivially) implies that

$$
\forall x \exists y (knows(x,y) \to (hates(y,Joe) \lor hates(y,Judy))) \\
\equiv \\
\forall x \exists y (\neg knows(x,y) \lor (hates(y,Joe) \lor hates(y,Judy)))
$$

holds too, but

$$
\forall x \exists y (knows(x,y) \land (hates(y,Joe) \lor hates(y,Judy)))
$$

does not since it requires $knows(x,y)$ to hold, for all $x$ and for some $y$. Therefore, the equivalence does not hold.

---

Finally, "everyone knows someone that hates Joe or Judy" is equivalent to

$$
\forall x \exists y (knows(x,y) \land (hates(y,Joe) \lor hates(y,Judy))).
$$

An intuition behind why this is the case is because "everyone *knows* $\ldots$" implies that, in the context, the resulting FOL formula must guarantee such a fact, which would not always be the case with the other (implicative) formula.

---

**References**

[1]: H. Andréka, J. van Benthem and I. Németi. Modal languages and bounded fragments of predicate logic. Journal of Philosophical Logic, 27:217–274, 1998. URL https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023/A:1004275029985.pdf

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. (There are automatic alerts to postings being a first for a contributor, an them being new. Along with hyperlinks like [Code of Conduct](https://cs.stackexchange.com/conduct), finding no unclear words about even `subtle put-downs`. There are overlaps with [Expected Behaviour](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).)

Answer (score 0):

Let me write short definitions in hope it will be helpful:
$$(\forall x\in X) R \Leftrightarrow (\forall x)(x\in X\Rightarrow R)$$
$$(\exists x\in X) R \Leftrightarrow (\exists x)(x\in X\land R)$$
As for order, then it matter. We have
$$(\exists x)(\forall y)R \Rightarrow (\forall y)(\exists x)R$$
but not reverse.